# Fuelphp: Can't load module's view from module's controller

Tags: view, module, fuelphp

Hi There need assistance here(specially those fuelphp developers),

I'm having these set-up on the fuelphp where I am using a module implementation. Below is my current set-up:

```
app
-modules
--design
---classes
---views
----admin
-----index.php
```

On my controller Controller_Admin I'm putting the code:

```
   $this->template->notification = \View::forge('common/notification.php');
```

It cause an error:

```
The requested view could not be found: common/notification.php
```

How can I load a view from my controller on my module? Any thoughts. Thank you.

Comment: have you enabled your module on config file?

Comment: yes, the module path and modules at always_load setting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently figured it out. I need to use the scope resolution (::) on this. :-) It works, I replaced my code to this:

```
$this->template->notification = \View::forge('design::common/notification');
```

Removing the extension and adding the module name with scope resolution solves the problem. :)

Comment: It is a good solution, but I suggest you to use Theme instead of Views: they are better for modules.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

namespace Adm;


class Controller_Adm extends \Controller {

    public static function action_index() {
       return \Response::forge(\View::forge('adm::adm/index'));
    }

}
```

a estrutara de  pastas é assim:

app
-modules
--adm
    ---classes
    ----controller
    ----model
    ----views  -> viewsModels
**---views**  -> views templates, páginas, html, etc
    **----adm

    -----index.php**